# Ошибка при компиляции transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug

Tags: java, android, apache

Ошибка

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
```

gradle:

```
  dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
        compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'

    }
```

**compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.3'** ругается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось решить удалением зависимости апачи и добавлением следующих

```
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.9'
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам компилятор пишет (желтая надпись)

Что `HttpClient` конфликтует с каким-либо пакетом из библиотеки андроид. Можете решить этот конфликт используя `HttpUrlConnection` или `OkHttp`.